# Android Messenger Application using services

Tags: android, web-services, broadcastreceiver, android-service, android-broadcast

I want to implement a simple messenger application for Android devices,I'm working with a web service which  contains all the required methods for sending and receiving(by pressing the send button a record will be inserted in the DB and by calling the receive method all the rows related to this receiver(user) are retrieved).

I've written a service in a separate class and in onStart() I check the receive method of my .Net web service,I start the service in  onCreate() of my activity ,so the service is in the background and receives the incoming messages perfectly,I can show the new message by using a toast directly in my service code,but I know that for accessing the views which are in my activity I should use pendingintent and maybe a BroadcastReceiver,so I can add the new messages to the main screen of my activity(for example a textview).
Now I want to find a way to access the textview of my activity and set the text of it through my service or anything else...
please help me on this issue,
Here is my activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyOwnActivity extends Activity
{
    Button btnSend;
    Button btnExtra;
    EditText txtMessageBody;
    TextView lblMessages;
    BerryService BS = new BerryService();
    public  void SetMessageHistory(String value)
    {
        txtMessageBody.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnExtra = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnExtraIntent);
        txtMessageBody = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtMessageBody);
        lblMessages = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessages);



        /////////

        //////////
        startService(new Intent(this, IncomingMessageService.class));

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // call webservice method to send

                BS.SetSoapAction("http://tempuri.org/Send");
                BS.SetMethodName("Send");
                String a = BS.SendMessage(txtMessageBody.getText().toString());
                lblMessages.setText(lblMessages.getText().toString() + "\n"
                        + txtMessageBody.getText().toString());
                txtMessageBody.setText("");

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is my service:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingMessageService extends Service
{
    private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID = 12;


    BerryService BS = new BerryService();
    String text = "";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Bind Failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "onCreate", 5000).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // ////////////////////////

        Toast.makeText(this, "onStart   ", 1000).show();
        // Timer Tick
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer _t = new Timer();
        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "tick   ", 1000)
                                .show();
                        // here the receive method should be called
                        BS.SetSoapAction("http://tempuri.org/RecieveMessage");
                        BS.SetMethodName("RecieveMessage");
                        String receivedMsg = BS.ReceiveMessage("sh");
                        //Instead of toast I want to access the textview in my activity!!!!!
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), receivedMsg, 5000).show();






                    }
                });
            }
        };
        _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(tt, 0, 1000);

    }



    // /
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "onDestroy", 5000).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends what web service you are working with. Is it JSON, XML? Android offers a range if ways to communicate with web services

Comment: I'm using KSOAP,and my web service in an ASP.Net web service.

Comment: I haven't had any experience with ksoap myself, but here is a seems-to-be-good tutorial I found when googling. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242

Comment: You said should you use a broadcast receiver? We'll broadcast receivers are good if you have the need to take action on events, SMS or intent broadcasts from other functions/activities. You can use the broadcast receiver it inform the user when new messages are received, just send the broadcast with intent when your code finds new rows or instances within the ksoap output (that's a rough idea of how it would work, my apologise I cannot delve deeper, I just woke up)

Comment: @SimonAddicott Thanks a lot,but please tell me exactly when I should find the new rows,on which event??? ...sorry if there is an ambiguity in my question...

Comment: Do you have any code? If so, include it into the question. Myself, and others can help better if there is a specific problem or question relating to the code

Comment: Which code you need?I can give you the methods of my web service but for the android code I don't have anything special,I mean only the codes to call the web service and get the result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand the concept of Broadcast, in your case it is the correct solution.

Start Broadcast in its activity

```
public static final String ACTION = "com.yourapp.ACTION.TEXT_RECEIVED";
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ////////

     mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           String msg = intent.getStringExtra("msg");
           yourTextView.setText(msg);
        }
     };

     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
     filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
     registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


    ////////
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    // remember to unregister the receiver
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mReceiver != null) {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

When you need to send the message of service you should use:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(MyOwnActivity.ACTION);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.putExtra("msg", "the message received by webservice");
i.putExtras(b);

sendBroadcast(i);
```

Have a look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Thanks a lot,I really appreciate your attention Eduardo.It works greatly!!

Answer (score 0):

Using a broadcast manager is great but I personally prefer to use square's Otto because it is just so easy to perform communication between components in an android application.

http://square.github.io/otto/

If you do choose to use otto, you are going to have to override the Bus's post method to be able to talk post messages to a bus on the foreground. Here is the code for that:

```
public class MainThreadBus extends Bus {
    private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override public void post(final Object event) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            super.post(event);
        } else {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    post(event);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```